# Pressing "Debug with Chrome" crashes expo ios build

Tags: expo, react-native-debugger

**Context:**

- I run an expo development build on an iOS device, the app loads properly and auto-refreshes properly
- I debug with react-native-debugger on linux (I need a way to see the redux state)

**Goal:**

- When I press on shake the iOS device and press "Open React Native dev menu" > then press "Debug with Chrome", I expect the react-native-debugger on my Linux computer to connect and display the state.

**Actual behaviour:**

1. On my iOS device:

> There was a problem loading the project.
>
> This development build encountered the following error:
>
> Connection to http://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy?role=Client timed
> out. Are you running node proxy? If you are running on the device,
> check if you have the right IP address in RCTWebSocketExecutor.m.

2. My react-native-debugger *correctly* displays the state.

How can I resolve this error? OR how do I use an alternative to react-native-debugger to see my state?

**Additional information:**

eas.json

```
{
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    },
    "development-simulator": {
      "extends": "development",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

app.json (select elements)

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      "@config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx"
    ],
    "jsEngine": "hermes",
    "ios": {
      "jsEngine": "jsc",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.anonymous.supi"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.BLUETOOTH",
        "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN",
        "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"
      ],
      "package": "com.anonymous.supi"
    },
  }
}
```